# "Printed" PDF from Firefox too big

Tags: macos, firefox, pdf

I often "print" some webpages into pdf files. Therefore I created an own stylesheet for that webpages so I have only the text I need (I'm using the addon stylish for it).

The problem: If I save the page to a pdf file, it becomes relatively huge. Example: I copied the text to LibreOffice and exported it to a pdf file. The result: about 100kb. With Firefox: 1.8 MB!! And it's only text! (I need that small smize, because I have to email the files)

Does anyone know how I can reduce those files? Maybe with ghostscript or any other commandline-tool?

EDIT:
Sorry, forgot to say: I'm using a Mac!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, I can't believe it!!! I found the solution: Removing the original stylesheets (manually with Firebug or with a greasemonkey script) of the page was the trick. I don't know, where the bug is (Firefox or Mac OS)... it seems, that the background-images of whatever are saved into the pdf, altough they are completely hidden via my stylesheet.

Thanks for your help!